# Remover primeira tag <p> e última tag </p> de string com jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho uma string com várias tags HTML. Quero remover apenas a primeira tag `<p>` e a última tag `</p>` desta string. Encontrei soluções que removem todas as tags mas estas não servem.

Exemplo:

```html
<p> 
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
  <p> Nullam feugiat, turpis at pulvinar vulputate</p> 
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
</p>
```

Deveria ficar:

```html
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
<p> Nullam feugiat, turpis at pulvinar vulputate</p> 
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
```

Comment: Acho que não tem muito jeito a não ser manipular a string diretamente. As tags estão logo no começo/fim da string, como `<p>alguma coisa</p>` ou é uma coisa mais misturada do tipo `<div><div><p>algumacoisa</p></div></div>`?

Comment: Sempre no começo e no fim

Comment: Amanda não percebi bem, quer remover apenas e só `<p>` do inicio e `</p>` do fim. Ou quer remover o primeiro/ultimo  `<p>` por completo: `<p>REMOVER</p><p>NÂO REMOVER</p><p>REMOVER</p>`

Comment: Editei a pergunta pra mostrar como deveria ficar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acho que isso resolve!

```
var s = "<p>uma coisa<p>outra coisa</p></p>";
s = s.substring(s.indexOf("<p>") + 3, s.lastIndexOf("</p>"));
```

Agora se o texto nem sempre conter a tag `<p>`, aí vai precisar fazer umas verificações adicionais.

Comment: Perfeito!! É justamente o que preciso, obrigada